# Determine if onEdit() was triggered by inserting or removing a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

- I have two spreadsheets, SS1 and SS2.
- I need to update SS2 when a row is inserted into or removed from SS1, or when a certain range of cells is changed in SS1.
- I use an installed onChange() trigger to call a function to determine when a row is inserted or removed from SS1 as follows:

```
function changeHappened(e)
{
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW" || e.changeType == "REMOVE_ROW")
  {
    // do an autoresize in SS2
  }
}
```

- This works perfectly.
- I also need to do the autoresize in SS2 when a cell is changed within a certain range in SS1. I can't use onChange() for that because row and column information isn't available via onChange(), so I use an installed onEdit() trigger to call a function to determine if the change happened in the range I'm interested in and if so, to do the autoresize in SS2.
- The problem is, inserting and removing rows not only fires onChange(), it also fires onEdit(). I need a way to determine in the function called by onEdit() if what happened was a row being added or removed because I don't want to update SS2 twice. I have tried many things, but haven't found a reliable test.

QUESTION: Can someone suggest a reliable test in an onEdit() called function to tell if the trigger happened due to inserting or removing a row?

I have tried checking the sheet, row, and column available in the onEdit() function, but they seem to come back with random values when a row is inserted or deleted. When I delete rows, sometimes the current sheet is even reported as another sheet in the spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> row and column information isn't available via onChange()

You can determine the active row and column in an [installable "on change" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) like this:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  const rowIndex = activeRange.getRow();
  const columnIndex = activeRange.getColumn();
```

> reliable test in an onEdit() called function to tell if the trigger happened due to inserting or removing a row?

`e.value` and `e.oldValue` will both be `undefined`, but I think that may happen in some other contexts as well, such as multi-cell range cut and paste.

It would probably make sense to include all the necessary logic in `changeHappened(e)`.

Comment: Thanks @doubleunary for this answer. It solved my problem perfectly. My understanding of the data available in onChange() was obviously mistaken (based on someone else's post I read). I have eliminated the onEdit() trigger, which simplifies my script significantly.